# Default location of vim-plug installed plugins for neovim

Tags: vim, neovim, vim-plugin

I wanted to work on one of the vim plugins that I had installed using vim-plug for my neovim, and was trying to avoid another copy of the plugin repo. But I am unable to find the default directory in which the plugins that have been installed are kept.

I lack a lot of knowledge about vim so I tried googling but was unable to find anything, also went through the init.vim but was unable to find anything.

Comment: It's whatever you set yourself in `plug#begin(PLUGIN_DIRECTORY)`. How is anyone on SO supposed to know what you wrote in your own files?

Comment: @friedrich You don't have to necessarily mention the PLUGIN_DIRECTORY, which I haven't done, thus the issue.

Comment: Makes no difference from my point of view. It's your setup and if you don't supply an option, the default one is picked. Which is [documented in the README](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug#example), BTW. Both the problem and the solution exist only on your machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it myself, and thus answering it on my own, will help some other helpless soul or me if I forget again (most likely scenario). The location is

`~/local/share/nvim/plugged/`

Answer (score -1):

Vim plugins are stored in

`~/.vim/plugin`

Terminal:
`cd ~/.vim/plugin`

Comment: That's Vim's own plugin path. OP was asking about plugins installed with [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) and that let's you specify the path.